# Colocar uma div atrás da outra

Tags: javascript, html, css

Não consigo de jeito algum fazer isso funcionar. Estou usando o "animate.css" pra fazer as animações dos elementos aparecendo, porém quando um elemento está subindo, no final da página por exemplo, todo o conteúdo daquela seção passa por cima do footer, deixando um efeito "feio". Porém acredito que se o footer estivesse acima da div, isso não seria perceptível.

[image: Imagem que mostra o que acontece]

Basicamente eu queria que o conteúdo "saísse atrás" do rodapé. No css/html não tem nada demais, só a classe do animate no conteúdo, altura dos blocos e cor

Comment: Bem vindo, favor detalhe melhor sua dúvida, imagens, código, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adicione um valor de z-index para seu footer maior do que o corpo que está passando por cima dele.

Essa regra define em qual posição do eixo Z seu elemento ficará, o arquivo com o maior valor ficará sempre em cima dos outros

```
footer{
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: Pra isso eu preciso adicionar position né? Vou ter que colocar em todos os elementos e arrumar tudo novamente

Comment: Sim, mas você pode colocar position relative sem os offsets e irá funcionar

Comment: Acabei de testar isso antes de ver o comentário e deu certo, mas agora que você falou tenho a certeza que vai ficar de boa. Valeu!!